# MVC .Net can't get it to stop trying to recreate tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I had migrations enabled - however, now I'm moving to the live server, it appears migrations are still trying to update the database, as I get the error:

`CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'secn'.`

I have this in a context file in my models folder:

```
namespace lhts2.Models
{
     public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
     {
            public DefaultConnection() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DefaultConnection>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

...and in my web.config file, my connection string is:

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=[servername];
  Initial Catalog=secn; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have deleted the Migrations folder too, and republished - but still I get the error above.

I also have this in my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Do I need to set the SetInitializer in some other place, other than in the context file in my models folder?

Thanks for any advice,

Mark

Comment: Do you have any EF initialization in the web.config file?

Comment: Hi Brandon - I think so - I've updated my question with the parts of EF mentioned in the web.config - thank you,

Comment: You have something else like a membership provider that may be trying to create tables?

Comment: No - it was a clean project I started from VS2013 - I did add the entity framework, and did one update-database for the local database - other than that, I've not added any other packages or providers.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/entity-framework-database-initialization):

> ...the initializer should have been set in the static constructor of your context. The static constructor is called before any constructors and is executed once. This is what we want. The reason is that in some of your application, you may initialize more than once the context. You do not want to execute all the process to check if the database if ready to be changed or not.

So, you should change your class to have a static constructor that is only called one time.

```
namespace lhts2.Models
{
     public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
     {
        static DefaultConnection()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DefaultConnection>(null);
        }

        public DefaultConnection() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the advice - I changed my context to exactly that, and now get this message: lhts2.Models.DefaultConnection.DefaultConnection()': static constructor cannot have an explicit 'this' or 'base' constructor call C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Webapps\lhts2\lhts2\Models\LHTS2Context.cs

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer. It wasn't clear from that article whether or not to include it, so I made the wrong decision. It should work without the base constructor call, though.

Comment: Thanks again - for some reason, I'm still getting the error: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'lhtssecn'.

Comment: So, the user that you have registered in the `DefaultConnection` connection string doesn't have CREATE TABLE permissions. You need to add them to your database (you should probably back it up just in case, first). It is best to run an initializer with higher permissions than the application so it can do its work.

Comment: Hi NightOwl888 - you got it - I still don't know why it was trying to create a table, but giving it permissions done the trick.  If you want to add as an answer, I'll mark it as such.  Thanks for your help, Mark

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Setting the IIS user to a "sysad" level user allowed the application to work normally. However that is not a secure method of solving the problem.

Further research revealed that the "migrations" table (named dbo.__MigrationHistory) was the culprit. I had given the IIS user access (Select, Update, Delete, Insert, and References) to all the "application" tables, but not the "migrations" table. Consequently when the application runs and attempts to determine if a migration is necessary, the access fails because of the lack of access rights for that user and the application thinks it needs to create the database and tables - which this user clearly should not have rights to do.

By providing normal access rights to the __MigrationHistory table (Select, Update, Delete, Insert, and References) the IIS user was now able to determine that no migration was necessary and therefore did not attempt to conduct a migration.
[Example of Permission Settings Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFvyy.png)